# Cannot use import statement outside a module react

Tags: reactjs, import

I am trying compile my app, and it has backend error. It said:

```
import express from "express";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bella/Desktop/EarlyBird/server.js:19:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

[please click here to see my backend structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcSrU.png)

Comment: If you are not transpiling your code (e.g. using babel or typescript) than that's might be an invalid statement in node JS (depending on which version are you using). You should use `const express = require('express')`.

Comment: Hi, I just replaced with "const express = require("express");", but it still got error, now indicated "import { signin, signup } from "../controllers/user.js";" errror here

Comment: Do the same `const { signin, signup } = require('../controller/users.js')`

Comment: Thank you so much! I replaced all my import statements with the format you offered. Now it works!